# How do I join tables on multiple conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I have to select data from two tables using join both are working individual but not working together, when i execute complete query it does not work but when execute both joins individually Example:

```
select 
dbo.mail_Messages.Subject,
dbo.mail_Messages.Body,
dbo.mail_Messages.Date,
dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
--dbo.mail_Messages.ParrentId
from
dbo.mail_Messages
join
dbo.mail_Reply as mr1
on
mr1.MessageID = dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
```

====================================================

```
select 
dbo.mail_Messages.Subject,
dbo.mail_Messages.Body,
dbo.mail_Messages.Date,
dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
from
dbo.mail_Messages
join
dbo.mail_Reply as mr2
on
mr2.ParrentId = dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
```

Above queries work fine.

But when I execute below query (Combination of above queries) it returns nothing.

```
select 
dbo.mail_Messages.Subject,
dbo.mail_Messages.Body,
dbo.mail_Messages.Date,
dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
--dbo.mail_Messages.ParrentId
from
dbo.mail_Messages
join
dbo.mail_Reply as mr1
on
mr1.MessageID = dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
join
dbo.mail_Reply as mr2
on
mr2.ParrentId = dbo.mail_Messages.MessageID
```

I have also attached an image:

[image]

Comment: Use left join in last two joins @Learner

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I use left join it returns all rows.

Comment: I don't see columns selected from other tables than "mail_Messages", neither where clause is there. so why to have join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to filter according with Message Id or ParentID and return the status of message

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.* 
FROM mail_Reply T2
JOIN mail_Messages T1 ON (T2.[MESSAGE ID]=T1.[MESSAGE ID] OR T2.PARENTID=T1.[MESSAGE ID])
```

Now if you want to filter with Message Id or ParentID append the code with the below code

```
AND (T2.[MESSAGE ID]=2 OR T2.PARENTID=2)
```

Now if you want to filter with Message Id or ParentID and UserID append the code with the below code

```
AND (T2.[MESSAGE ID]=2 OR T2.PARENTID=2) AND T2.USERID=1
```